Wi-Fi Randomly Crashing Unbutu 22.04.4
My PC did not come with a wireless module, so I had to buy a wireless USB adapter, which seems to be working just fine, but when I'm using the Wi-fi for maybe longer than an hour the connection randomly crashes. I have to disconnect from my current network and connect it again to make it work. Does anybody know what this issue might be?
System info:
  OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
  Kernel: 6.5.0-26-generic
  Shell: bash 5.1.16
  DE: GNOME 42.9
  CPU: Intel i5-4590 (4) @ 3.700GHz
  GPU: AMD ATI Radeon 540/540X/550/550
  Memory: 1676MiB / 7885MiB

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager. Read man journalctl NetworkManager service. Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.
